# How to indefinitely run commands based on various daytimes using Bash?

Tags: bash, cron

I'm trying to write a bash script and add it on `rc.local` in *Raspberry Pi* to startup with each boot, stays in the background, and show different images depending on the time of the day. A different full-screen image for morning, afternoon and night.

My commands to obtain that are:

```
feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B white -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/1-Morning/
feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B white -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/2-Afternoon/
feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B black -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/3-Night/
```

All the commands above working individually and opening correct images that I want, but when I move these command to Bash script, they stop working. I've tried to do it with ***while*** yet no luck:

```
#!/bin/bash
fireup()
while [ $(date +"%T") -ge 06:00:00 ] && [ $(date +"%T") -lt 12:00:00 ];
  do
  killall feh ; feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B white -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/1-Morning/;
  while [ $(date +"%T") -ge 12:00:00 ] && [ $(date +"%T") -lt 19:00:00 ];
  do
  killall feh ; feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B white -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/2-Afternoon/
while [ $(date +"%T") -ge 19:00:00 ] && [ $(date +"%T") -lt 06:00:00 ];
  do
  killall feh ; feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B black -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/3-Night/
done
done
done
```

I've also tried `crontab` but nothing happened.

I would appreciate it if someone would help.

Comment: Are you running X11? I'd guess you need to tell `feh` how to access your display.

Comment: No, I'm on Raspbian Stretch with a desktop.

Comment: As far as I know feh needs X11. What happens if you run the command `xdpyinfo|grep vendor` from a terminal on your desktop?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ xdpyinfo|grep vendor ---
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation ---
vendor release number:    11902000

Comment: As I said in the post, feh command working and opening image with no issue but I think what I'm doing is bash script is incorrect.

Comment: You are running X11. Will you be logged in all the time? Do you want the background images to change when you are logged out?

Comment: Auto-login in Raspbian is ON by default and I want the full-screen picture to start playing as soon as boot. I can change the Raspberry configuration and boot into CLI instead of desktop if you suggesting that. But no one would have physical access to this unit and this device would be for this single purpose and only to play different image on different time of day.

Comment: The screensaver is also disabled so as long as the device stays ON it only showing the fullscreen image no matter if it's on CLI or on Desktop. I'm currently testing the feh command on a desktop terminal and it's working fine but bash script running from same desktop doesn't do anything.

Comment: I am assuming he issue is from the way I implemented those "while" on my script.

Comment: Running the script from `rc.local` is just wrong. Start it from your session login script instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code declares a function in a slightly unusual way.

Most often, a function is written:

```
name() { commands }
```

whereas you have:

```
name() while ... done
```

This disguised the fact that although you declare a function, you never actually run it!

So, the solution is either:

- delete the line `fireup()` - in which case the while loop will simply run
- append a line `fireup` to invoke the function

Beyond that, the logic of the while has problems. Consider:

```
while [ $(date +"%T") -ge 06:00:00 ] && [ $(date +"%T") -lt 12:00:00 ];
```

This tries to compare two sets of strings as if they were numbers, which will never succeed and should result in some kind of error being displayed.

Instead try:

```
while [[ $(date +%T) > 05:59:59 && $(date +%T) < 12:00:00 ]];
```

Comment: It'dosent work. Error: ./fireup: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `export'
./fireup: line 3: `export DISPLAY=:0.0'

Comment: I will try to find a way to record my desktop in Raspbian on Monday when I had some time so you can see the issue.

Comment: run your bash script through `shellcheck` and see what it points out: http://shellcheck.net (or probably available to install in raspbian)

Comment: Ok, the issue is definitely not communicating with the X server as I just made another script including only:`#!/bin/bash
feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B white -F --zoom max -r 1.png` and it's working fine. So issue is somewhere on my `while loops`.

Comment: did you run that script from crontab or rc.local ?

Comment: Just from a terminal. I'm testing this while loop in a terminal first and it doesn't work. rc.local or crontab would be the next step when I made sure the script does what it supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that and removed the `fireup()` line completely yesterday. Thanks but still no luck.

Comment: The other problem is that `-ge` `-lt` expect  integers not strings

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@jhnc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10971581/jhnc), I have two code that working now.

First code with `while`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ $(date +%T) > 05:59:59 && $(date +%T) < 12:00:00 ]];
  do
  killall feh
  feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B white -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/1-Morning/
  done
while [[ $(date +%T) > 11:59:59 && $(date +%T) < 19:00:00 ]];
  do
  killall feh
  feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B white -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/2-Afternoon/
  done
while [[ $(date +%T) > 18:59:59 && $(date +%T) < 06:00:00 ]];
  do
  killall feh
  feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B black -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/3-Night/
  done
```

Second code with `if`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do   
   currenttime=$(date +%H:%M:%S)
   if [[ "$currenttime" > "05:59:59" ]] && [[ "$currenttime" < "12:00:00" ]]; then
   killall feh ; feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B white -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/1-Morning/
   elif [[ "$currenttime" > "11:59:59" ]] && [[ "$currenttime" < "19:00:00" ]]; then
   killall feh ; feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B white -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/2-Afternoon/
   else
   killall feh ; feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B black -F --zoom max -r ~/Pictures/3-Night/
   fi
done
```

The only issue with these two codes above is that the first true `while` in first code or the first true `if` in the second code, run the correspondent `feh` but this `feh` will never end so the first true loop or condition will stays ON forever and as long as this `feh` stays ON it will never check the other time of days to change the picture.
I've added `killall feh` in `crontab` on every morning, afternoon and night which causes the code to jump into the next loop or condition check. It's not the most efficient way to do it but it's working now. Thanks.